# Drupal8 EntityQuery failing on sort

Tags: drupal-8

I am currently using the Entityquery API in Drupal8. I have some code that fails whenever I try to sort, but which works if I remove the sort line. I have checked the log and I cannot see anything about the error in the log.

See below.

This works:

```
$query->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'programme')      
  ->range(0,5);
```

This Doesn't

```
$query->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'programme')
  ->sort('changed', 'DESC')
  ->range(0,5);
```

Please can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: I don't anything about this, but have you  tried set the range before the sort ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some similar code before. It seems that there is no problem in your code. One thing that you maybe forgot, is the "execute()" method should be called at last. So the code will be like the followings.

```
$query->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'programme')
  ->sort('changed', 'DESC')
  ->range(0,5)
  ->execute();
```